# Adding customize DatagridviewRow using binding source in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, customization

Is there a way to add a customize DatagridviewRow using c#?

Ive made a class for the rows.

```
class CustomizeRow: System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow
{
    ...
}
```

Now i can add some of my customize row

```
        DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

        CustomizeRow row = new CustomizeRow();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

But how can i handle when i am using binding source to add rows like this

```
        bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataSet1.Tables["Table"];
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: could you try to use the onrowdatabound event?

Comment: previous contribution was the solution.
Customrow rowtemp = new CustomRow();
            dataGridView1.RowTemplate = rowtemp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [DataGridView.RowTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowtemplate.aspx).

From the MSDN page on the RowTemplate:

> Setting the row template is necessary when external data is displayed
>   using custom types derived from the DataGridViewRow class. With
>   unbound DataGridView controls, you can programmatically populate the
>   Rows collection with instances of your custom row type. When
>   displaying external data, however, the rows are generated
>   automatically, but they are based on the row template, which you can
>   set to an instance of your custom row type.

So you can simply set the template row like so:

```
CustomizeRow row = new CustomizeRow(); 
dataGridView1.RowTemplate = row;
```

Comment: @Marius - thanks, didn't mean to nag :) but some new users don't know how things work. Welcome to StackOverflow